# HashMap iterating and deleting element

Tags: java

```
public void execute(HashMap<String,Coordonnee >c)
{
    c.forEach((k,v) -> {
        p = m.getMin(c);
        sky.add(p);
        c.remove(p.getNom());
    });
}
```

This throws a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

How can I fix that ?

Comment: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re

Comment: Googling "java hashmap ConcurrentModificationException" would have really benn faster for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use removeIf function:
   `map.entrySet().removeIf`
2. Use iterator:

   ```
   Iterator<Object> it = map.keySet().iterator();

   while (it.hasNext())
   {
      it.next();
      if (something)
          it.remove();
   }
   ```

Comment: i don't have a condition but the min element after getting it i would delete it

Answer (score 0):

you cannot delete an element of the list while looping through it. You should use Iterator for that.

```
public void execute(HashMap<String,Coordonnee >c)
{
    Iterator cItr = c.iterator();
    while(cItr.hasNext())
    {
        c = cItr.next();
        p = m.getMin(c);
        sky.add(p);
        cItr.remove(p.getNom());
    }
}
```

Comment: remove() in iterator can not be applied (String) !